# Covariant Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, reference-frames, maxwell-equations, covariance

As we know, the covariant form of Maxwell's equations (there are 2 equations in this formulation) are covariant under Lorentz transformation. Are these equations covariant under general transformation，i.e. transformation from inertial frames to non-inertial frames?

Answer (score 6):

Maxwell's equations still hold AND covariant for curved spacetimes, but with a slightly modified formulation. Not to mention that we also need to redefine what covariance means.

For example, one has to use covariant derivative $\nabla_\alpha$ instead of ordinary $\partial_\alpha$, and the equations will be
$$
\nabla_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta} = \mu_0 J^\beta, \quad \nabla_{[\alpha} F_{\beta\gamma]} = 0
$$
where $J^\beta$ denotes the current density. (The second $\nabla_\alpha$ can be replaced by $\partial_\alpha$ though for GR spacetimes)

If one tries to use potential $A^\alpha$ instead of field strength $F^{\alpha\beta}$, then the discrepancy goes worse. The first equation of the above two becomes
$$
\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha A^\beta - R^\beta{}_\alpha A^\alpha = \mu_0 J^\beta
$$
where $R^\beta{}_\alpha$ is the Ricci curvature of the spacetime.

Now for the good news: in differential form formulation, the formulation doesn't really change whether we work on a curved spacetime or a flat one. The Maxwell equations are:
$$
\star ~d \star F = \mu_0 J, \quad dF = 0
$$

A quick reference is in Wikipedia, for example [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Relativistic_formulations).

Comment: You mean the non-inertial frame is equivalent to curved spacetime?

Comment: @Kksen you can have non inertial frames in flat spacetime, but in curved spacetime all frames are non-inertial. So if you can write something for curved spacetime then it also applies to non inertial frames in flat spacetime

Comment: @Dale If there is a non-inertial frame in a flat spacetime, is it true that the metric in that frame would be non-Lorentzian? If yes, is it possible that the Riemann curvature tensor components in this kind of frame be non-zero?

Comment: @Kksen Yes and Yes. However, even if the Riemann curvature tensor components are non-zero, all of your curvature invariants will be zero. In other words, it is still flat.

Comment: @Dale Can you give some examples of such invariants?

Comment: e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature

Answer (score -1):

Nope, they are not covariant. In non-inertial frames plane waves change their frequency, which does not happen in inertial frames.